# How to select two points on a map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, select

I need to select two points on a map in QGIS.  I selected the element selection tool in menu view and I want to select two points.  How can I accomplish this? Are there other tools or methods to select points in QGIS?

Answer (score 6):

There are a few general ways to accomplish this:

1. Use the select features tool (see first figure)
2. Select by attributes manually (Right-click on layer > open attribute table) (highlighted in orange)
3. Search by SQL (highlighted in red)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To select multiple features. Click `View Menu` -> `Select` -> `Select Features by Freehand`.
and you can select point by drawing very small on the point. For multiple point use `Ctrl` key